# Sequelize Op.notIn with Sequelize Model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Hello i have a mysql query which is working fine in sequelize.query and the query is

```js
select list_name from lists l where l.list_id not in
(SELECT sub.list_id from list_sub_activities sub left join.
 Activities a on a.list_act_id = sub.list_act_id where a.agency_id = 2)
```

and i want to do the same using the sequelize model, i have tried but i think i am missing something.

**List of Package ---> lists**

```js
List_of_Packages.findAll({
  attributes: ['list_name'],
  where: {
    list_id: {
      [Op.notIn]: [List_sub_Activities.findAll({
        attributes: ['list_id'],
        include: {
          model: Activities,
          required: false,
          where: {
            agency_id: 2
          }
        }
      })
      ]
    }
  }


}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

I appreciate that if you help me.

**Thank you !!!**

Comment: change  `[Op.in]` with `[Op.ne]` and try.

Comment: @DhavalDarji Thank you for the comment but it did not work. Sorry i forgot to add `[Op.notIn]`

Comment: you solved this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findAll()` (and other query methods) are asynchronous so you will need to resolve the promise (or use a callback) to resolve the value before you can pass the `list_id`s to `Op.notIn`. It will also return an array of *objects* with a property of `list_id`, so you will need to map this to an array of integers before you can use it. You can also pass in `raw: true` so that it will not generate Sequelize Instances from your results and will instead return plain javascript objects - this is more efficient than creating objects just to fetch a single property.

By setting `required: false` on the `Activities` include you will be returning all `List_sub_Activities` and not filtering on them (some will be null in your results). This is likely not what you intended.

This example uses `async/await` for clarity instead of `thenables`. Note that this is **not** the most efficient as it requires multiple database queries, the ideal solution would be to use a `LEFT JOIN` and then remove items where the `package.list_id IS NULL` (see second example).

```js
// get an array of Activities with the list_id set
const activities = await List_sub_Activities.findAll({
  attributes: ['list_id'],
  include: {
    model: Activities,
    // don't use required: false to only return results where List_sub_Activities.Activities is not null
    // required: false,
    where: {
      agency_id: 2,
    },
  },
  raw: true,
});

// map the property to an array of just the IDs
const activityIds = activities.map((activity) => activity.list_id);

// now you can pass the activityIds to Op.notIn
const packages = await List_of_Packages.findAll({
  attributes: ['list_name'],
  where: {
    list_id: {
      [Op.notIn]: activityIds,
    },
  },
});
```

With thenables.

```js
List_sub_Activities.findAll(...)
.then((activities) => activities.map((activity) => activity.list_id))
.then((activityIds) => List_of_Packages.findAll(...))
.then((packages) => {
  console.log(packages);
});
```

This example LEFT JOINs `List_of_Packages` to `List_sub_Activities` which is JOINed to `Activities` with a WHERE setting the `agency_id` to 2, then only returns results from `List_of_Packages` where the `List_sub_Activities.list_id` is `NULL` (nothing was matched on the LEFT JOIN). This should return the same results as above in a single query.

```
// Get List_of_Packages where there is no match in List_sub_Activities after 
// it is joined to Activities with the agency_id set.
const agencyId = 2;
const packages = await List_of_Packages.findAll({
  attributes: ['list_name'],
  include: {
    model: List_sub_Activities,
    // we don't need to actually fetch the list_id
    attributes: [],
    include: {
      model: Activities,
      where: {
        agency_id: agencyId,
      },
    },
    // uses a LEFT JOIN
    required: false,
  },
  // only return results where the List_sub_Activities.list_id is null
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('List_sub_Activities.list_id'), 'IS', null),
});
```